# Issue with CKAN stored resource URL’s

Tags: ckan

When static resources (csv, txt, etc.) are stored on the CKAN server, we are unable to retrieve/download the resources using the web interface.

All of the files which have been manually uploaded get a download URL of the server IP address of which CKAN is running. This is different than the external domain name. I’ve already set the clan.site_url to the external one, but the download URL is still pointing to the IP address.

This is what CKAN is currently showing: https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/storage/f/2016-04-14T18%3A13%3A10.373Z/test.zip where xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx is my public IP address.

If I manually replace the IP address with our domain name, it works as intended.

Is there a setting I need to add/change in order to fix this issue?

Comment: Have you uploaded any files since you changed the site_url?

Comment: All of the new resources work, but what would be the best way to update the old resources?

Comment: Try to dump the database and then reload it. As far as I remember, this should correct the old URLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quickest way to fix this (but probably not the cleanest) is **something like**:

1. Backup your DB
2. psql ckan
3. `update resource_revision set url = replace(url, 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx', 'domain.name');`
4. `update resource set url = replace(url, 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx', 'domain.name');`
5. \q
6. Rebuild search index.